# How to insert a new value into lang file with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, lang

I knew that Laravel has `Lang::get('xxx');` function

But when the string `xxx` was not an key in the lang array => it will just display `xxx`, then I have to manually type a new key => value into the lang file.

So is there anyway that if `xxx` not available in the lang file, it will automatically insert a new key and value to the lang file. like this:

```
return array(
   'xxx' => '',
);
```

Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this package [Laravel Translation Manager](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Example; In laravel8 you can use in

`resources->lang->en->auth.php`

return [

```
'xxx' => 'xxxxxx',
'yyy' => 'yyyyyyyyy',
```

];

When you call; you can use

```
{{Lang::get('auth.xxx')}}
{{Lang::get('auth.yyy')}}
```